# MVC POST Request in controller

Tags: json, http, post, model-view-controller, http-post

I am new to MVC and need a bit of help refactoring my code. In my view I have a http 'POST' request to a known URL that gets triggered when a user enters a new Client Name. The end point URL then returns three unique keys in json format that I then display on my UI. So I have four text boxes that display the following info:

Client Name: newclient
Key1: xyz
key2: 123foo
keys3: 456bar

My question is how do I make this request from the controller instead of everything taking place in the view ? I'm struggling to see how I can make the POST request from the controller when I need the information entered from the user in the view.

Thanks

Comment: Am unable to understand your question. You want to make a POST request to an MVC action in a controller from another MVC action in a controller?

Comment: i want to make a POST request to a separate URL outside of my MVC project. I'm currently doing this in the view but wanted to know if this is possible to make this POST request from the controller instead ? So i want to pass my clientname from the view to my controller and POST to my url if that make sense ?

Comment: So, the POST request is to a webservice to get json response and then use it in your UI. Are you not able to make a webservice call from C# code? If the call is to an independent webservice, it would be better to do it from the view (client) itself. If you want to do it from your controller, it will work but unnecessary latency caused from client to your controller to the independent webservice and return to the client finally.

Comment: Yes that's correct - if it is counter intuitive to make the call from the controller I will keep my code as it is and call the web service straight from the view. Thanks for your help.